# Confusing behaviour of const_get in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

According to the documentation `mod.const_get(sym)` "Returns the value of the named constant in mod."

I also know that `const_get` by default may look up the inheritance chain of the receiver. So the following works:

```
class A; HELLO = :hello; end
class B < A; end
B.const_get(:HELLO) #=> :hello
```

I also know that classes in Ruby subclass `Object`, so that you can use `const_get` to look up 'global' constants even though the receiver is a normal class:

```
class C; end
C.const_get(:Array) #=> Array
```

However, and this is where i'm confused -- modules do not subclass `Object`. So why can I still look up 'global' constants from a module using `const_get`? Why does the following work?

```
module M; end
M.const_get(:Array) #=> Array
```

If the documentation is correct - `const_get` simply looks up the constant defined under the receiver or its superclasses. But in the code immediately above, `Object` is not a superclass of `M`, so why is it possible to look up `Array` ?

Thanks

Comment: Note that this does not match the behavior of `::`. `SomeModule::SomeGlobalConstant` will cause an error, whereas `SomeModule.const_get(:SomeGlobalConstant)` will work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are correct to be confused... The doc didn't state that Ruby makes a special case for lookup of constants in `Modules` and has been modified [to state this explicitly](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#const_get-method). If the constant has not been found in the normal hierarchy, Ruby restarts the lookup from `Object`, as can be [found in the source](http://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_9_2_preview3/variable.c#L1594).

Constant lookup by itself can be bit confusing. Take the following example:

```
module M
  Foo = :bar
  module N
    # Accessing Foo here is fine:
    p Foo # => bar
  end
end
module M::N
  # Accessing Foo here isn't
  p Foo  # => uninitialized constant M::N::Foo
end
p M::N.const_get :Foo  # => uninitialized constant M::N::Foo
```

In both places, though, accessing `Object` level constants like `Array` is fine (thank god!). What's going on is that Ruby maintains a list of "opened Module definitions". If a constant has an explicit scope, say `LookHereOnly::Foo`, then **only** `LookHereOnly` and its included modules will be searched. If no scope is specified (like `Foo` in the example above), Ruby will look through the opened module definitions to find the constant `Foo`: `M::N`, then `M` and finally `Object`. The topmost opened module definition is always `Object`.

So `M::N.const_get :Foo` is equivalent to accessing `Foo` when the opened classes are only `M::N` and `Object`, like in the last part of my example.

I hope I got this right, coz I'm still confused by constant lookups myself :-)

Comment: Any idea why it does that? In what cases would that be useful?

Comment: @sepp2k: not sure if it is _useful_, but I tried explaining what I think is the logic behind it.

Comment: It's not intuitive, but the M::N issue is due to lexical scope. If you do `module M; module N; end; end`, the contents of M are in the lexical scope of N (M is visible from N due to nesting). With `module M::N; end`, M is not visible because the containing scope is the top-level. Personally I try to avoid defining classes and modules in the M::N form - also because it's an error if M doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Interesting experiment ... try eval("M::N"), JRuby can do some interesting things with this approach as well. -- Yes it's eval and EVIL

Answer (score 2):

I came up with the following script to load name spaced constants:

```
def load_constant(name)
  parts = name.split('::')
  klass = Module.const_get(parts.shift)
  klass = klass.const_get(parts.shift) until parts.empty?
  klass
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as we are not checking for errors you can:

```
def load_constant(name)
    name.split('::').inject(Module) do |mod_path, mod_to_find|
      mod_path.const_get(mod_to_find)
    end
end
```